# Makefile.Release error: Making Zint Barcode project work in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, barcode

After acquiring [Zint Barcode generator](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/) i went into the folder backend_qt4 and opened the Qt project file backend_vcx.pro. This project does unfortunately not compile, with the error:

```
Makefile.Release: No such file or directory
```

What causes this error?

I'm using Qt5.2.1 with MinGW compiler.

Note: There is also a frontend_qt4 project, which displays the same error when i'm trying to compile it.

**Edit**: I downloaded zint-2.4.3.tar.gz [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zint/files/zint/2.4.3/)

Comment: Did you solved this issue? I'm also trying to compile it with no luck..

Comment: Unfortunately not. I compiled Zint and used it via commandline calls from my code. If you have problems compiling the dependend libpng and zlib, check out the videos from this guy: https://www.youtube.com/user/zbasenet

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info. BTW I was able to use zint in my Qt application by adding source files from backend and backend_qt4 directories to my Qt project. So now they are part of my app. Also I changed project to use c99 standard, because zint sources was incompatible with Qt's default.
It's not as clean as I wanted, but better than nothing.

Comment: I'm not too happy with the commandline approach either, but it works and my program is currently running on 8 machines which each uses the code around 300 times daily. It has been running for 3 weeks now, so it should be stable enough. It's too bad that it doesn't work with Qt "properly", but i'm glad to hear you got it working.